# how to add a circle at the top middle of tab in html?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am design a circle at the top middle of my tab but my tab will automatic increase based on the content i am using md-tab for creating the tab

I have created a circle  with css

```
.bubble_circle {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 15px;
    }
```

Please help me out from this problem .past one day i am trying to set the circle in the top middle of the tab but i am enable to do this .

Comment: try positioning the .bubble_circle element to absolute ---      .bubble_circle{position:absolute;}

Comment: please create a live demo using fiddle or something. It will be much easy for us to understand your problem.

Comment: I have tried with the {position :absolute} but the bubble is not aligning in the center based on the tab size @chandra shekhar

Comment: make the parent element of .bubble_circle to position:relative and set .bubble_circle position:absolute and give a try

Answer (score 2):

Use `position` to get the same

Below an example

```css
.tab {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto; /* You can update it as your need */
  background: tomato;
  position: relative;
  padding:5px;
}

.bubble_circle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  /* z-index: value; if need and change as your need */
}

.bubble_circle + p {
  padding-top:15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <div class="bubble_circle"></div>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima eaque quae incidunt ab, dolorum perspiciatis odit eius. Non assumenda doloremque in animi, laboriosam quibusdam nulla modi aspernatur sit enim voluptatum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: If the there more number of tabs and the tabs size will automatic increase or decrease based on the content in the tab then the bubble postion will change.

Comment: no it's stay in center top you can play with tab height

Comment: I think it will help for me. Thank you. @LKG

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this very easy with `flexbox`. Use `display: flex;` on the tab and `justify-content: center;` to center your child bubble on the top of the tab. No positions etc. needed.

```css
.tab {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.centered {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bubble_circle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 15px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <div class="centered">
      <div class="bubble_circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="centered ">
      <p>Tab</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```css
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.tab {
background-color: lightgray;
border-left: thin solid darkgray;
border-right: thin solid darkgray;
border-top: thin solid darkgray;
border-radius: 5px;
display: inline-block;
padding-top: 1em;
position: relative;
}
.bubble-circle {
position: absolute;
top: 1px;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='tab'>
<div class='bubble-circle'></div>
<p>Tab 1</p>
</div>
```